# Google maps RefererNotAllowedMapError in Electron application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, electron

When using google maps app packed with Electron application I'm facing RefererNotAllowedMapError error from Google which means current application url can't do requests to google maps using current APIKey.
Theoretically, we can whitelist application domains or set a wild-card (which I would like to omit) in google panel.

I tried multiple things:

- allowing requests from file:/// in google maps panel but google says that "file:///" is incorrect. The problem is that paths in electron have 3 slashes
- setting referrer using plugin (https://github.com/akameco/electron-referer) - no luck
- setting referrer using

  ```
  Object.defineProperty(document, "referrer", {get : function(){ return "mydomain.com"; }});
  ```
- setting referrer in loadUrl - no luck

  ```
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: 'index.html',
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
  }), {
      httpReferrer: 'mydomain.com',
  })
  ```

Is there any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the exact value of the `window.location.href` when you run the app?

Comment: @xomena It's file:///web/#/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Google Maps JavaScript API documentation:

> file:// referers need a special representation to be added to the Key restriction. The "file:/" part should be replaced with "__file_url__" before being added to the Key restriction. For example, "file:///path/to/" should be formatted as "__file_url__//path/to/*". After enabling file:// referers, it is recommended you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key-restrictions

So, in your case for `file:///web/#/` path you should define HTTP referrer restriction as

`__file_url__//web/*`

I hope this helps!